# Adding query timeout

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I created a report in SSRS. A report generated by the result of dataset that used a stored procedure. But the stored procedure took 20 minute runtime. How can I add query timeout for this report. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify timeouts for your report execution generally using SQL Server Management Studio R2. Open SSMS, chose Reporting Service as connection type. Logon with an administrative user. Under the root in object explorer, right click an chose Properties. Go to the Execution tab an chose the Limit in seconds (Default: 1800 = 30min).

Another way would be to limit the execution of a singe report. Open the Report in the designer and select your DataSet. Right click the DataSet and chose DataSet Properties. In the Query window you will find a Timeout property below (0 by default = infinite). Set it to a proper value in seconds.

Comment: I have set the timeout of dataset to 0. But the report still got timeout problem.

Comment: yes of course. probably you did not understand me correctly. I will repeat more detailed: 0 means infinite wait time = NO TIMEOUT. you have to set the value to a proper value for you like 120 for 2 minutes or any time in seconds, which is okay for you. Hope this could help you finally.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually manage the timeout within your deployed report.

Go to your SSRS url.
Click on the Report.
Click on Manage.
Click on Processing Options.
Within there you have three options to manage timeout.

Doing it this way means you can have a different timeout setting between your production and development environments.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround for me. Just limit your SP to select top 1 and temporarily remove any parameter that need to be keyed in , refresh dataset and then afterwards add back the params in the SP and add the parameters manually in rdl. After doing this remove the TOP function from the SELECT Statement.